# Oracle SQL script giving error. I try to create table

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I have script in Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "CONNECTIONS_DB"
("USER" VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
 "TIME" DATE NOT NULL,
 "STATUS" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "CONNECTIONS_DB_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USER", "TIME", "STATUS"),
);
```

and it returns next error:

```
Error starting at line : 616 in command -
CREATE TABLE "CONNECTIONS_DB"
("USER" VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
 "TIME" DATE NOT NULL,
 "STATUS" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "CONNECTIONS_DB_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USER", "TIME", "STATUS"),
)
Error report -
ORA-00904: : недопустимый идентификатор
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your code:

1) there is a trailing comma at the end of the line that declares the `CONSTRAINT`

2) datatype `BOOLEAN` does not exists in Oracle; you can use `NUMBER(1)` instead

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE "CONNECTIONS_DB" (
    "USER" VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
    "TIME" DATE NOT NULL,
    "STATUS" NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CONNECTIONS_DB_PK PRIMARY KEY ("USER", "TIME", "STATUS")
);
```

Side note: `USER` is a reserved word in Oracle. I would suggest using another identifier (like `USERNAME`), and removing the double quotes around the identifiers. This will save you the work of double quoting that column in all further queries:

```
CREATE TABLE CONNECTIONS_DB (
    USERNAME VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
    TIME DATE NOT NULL,
    STATUS NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CONNECTIONS_DB_PK PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME, TIME, STATUS)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62ba648e63c2b2a64478d299c28db63f)**